# how to show popup using ajax output

Tags: codeigniter

i want to show a popup message about to login the user. here iam using ajax function. 
if the success: part is true i want to show the popup message. pls help me thanks in adv.

```
  <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#squarespaceModal" class="btn green btn-success" onclick="going('<?echo $user_id;?>','<?echo $event_id;?>')">Going</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="squarespaceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">Ã—</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">My Modal</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <!-- content goes here -->
                        <form>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                            <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                            <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                          </label>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                  </form>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="group button">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"  role="button">Close</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-delete hidden" role="group">
                        <button type="button" id="delImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-red" data-dismiss="modal"  role="button">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <button type="button" id="saveImage" class="btn btn-default btn-hover-green" data-action="save" role="button">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**function going()**

```
      function going(user_id,event_id)
  {
    $.ajax({

        url: "<?echo base_url()?>events/event_going",
        type: 'post',   // HTTP METHOD
        data: 
        {user_id:user_id,event_id:event_id  },


        success: function(data)
        {  


                  if(data='true')
                  {
                     //pls check & add any suggsns
                  $('#squarespaceModal').dialog(data);  
                  }


            // document.getElementById('mysubmit').value="active";

          }

       });
    }
```

**controller**

```
    public function event_going()
  {      
    $user_id=$this->input->post('user_id');
    $event_id=$this->input->post('event_id');        
    $temp=$this->session->userdata('user');
    $going=$this->EM->is_going($event_id,$user_id);
    $going1=$this->EM->is_going1($event_id,$user_id);
    if($temp=="")
    {          
        echo "Please log in";

    }
    else if($going==$user_id)
        {
            echo "Already confirmed as going..";
        }
        else if($going1==$user_id)
            {
                echo "Are you sure you want to change... Press ok to continue";
                $this->EM->event_updation($event_id,$user_id);
            }
            else
            {           
                $data=array('event_id'=>$event_id,'ev_going'=>$user_id);             
                $this->EM->eventgoing($data);          
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, instead of showing a new popup, you can get the content of popup from ajax. What i mean is, on click of a button, call ajax function, get the content and have a div inside the modal-body, for example

```
<div class="dynamic-data">

</div>
```

and in ajax success function do like this

```
success: function(data){
    $(".dynamic-data").html(data);
}
```

Comment: but the popup get vanished immediately

Comment: have a normal button n dont change any of the popup functionality. Just the content of popup ll come from ajax.

Comment: ok no problem. Have a button. on which, if you click, you should get normal / empty popup. Is the above working??

Comment: What is not working?? popup or the content to popup??

Comment: popup not working. There is no popup after clicking the button

Comment: success: function(data)
            {         
                      if(data='true')
                      {
                       $("#squarespaceModal").html(data);
                          
                      }

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cp67J/1555/

See the link, on click call ajax function and put the data in dynamic-data. Instead of settimeout() call your ajax function here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87363/discussion-between-niranjan-and-roger-nm).